# Db.SaveChanges() not saving correctly at release mode

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to save a checkbox to db. It works right at debug mode but switching to release or custom release without code optimizations as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/) doesn't. Db is Sqlite. Looking with DB Browser for SQLite SimpleCheck field is just NULL or 0 at release and NULL, 0 or 1 at debug. (Edited)

```
        private void SetSingleCheck(CheckBox box)
    {
        var processId = (int)box.Tag;
        using (var db = new AgendaContext())
        {
            var check = db.Checks.SingleOrDefault(c => (c.ProcessId == processId) && (c.Date.Date == SelectedDate.Date.Date));
            if (null == check)
            {
                check = new Check()
                {
                    ProcessId = processId,
                    Date = SelectedDate.Date
                };
                db.Checks.Add(check);
            }
            if  (box.IsChecked.HasValue)
            {
                check.SimpleCheck = box.IsChecked.Value;
            }                
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Relevant parts of the model, just in case:

```
    public class Check //Check if this process is ok or not, TODAY
{
    public int CheckId { get; set; }        
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public Process Process { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public bool? SimpleCheck { get; set; } //USed for checked situations. example: clean this thing: Ok, i have cleaned it.
    public bool? DoubleCheck { get; set; } //Used for ok/no ok after doing something.
    public ObservableCollection<Temperature>Temperatures { get; set; }
}
        public DbSet<Check>Checks { get; set; }
```

What is wrong or missing? Thank you.

Comment: So you've stepped through the code in release mode, it's entering the above SetSingleCheck method, the box.IsChecked has a value which is going into SimpleCheck prior to the SaveChanges call, and there isn't any exception getting thrown/eaten?

Just to clarify, by checking the "HasValue" you're basically saying that the checkbox will default to the indeterminate state, only once a user clicks on it to set it to true, false, (or back to indeterminate) will that SimpleCheck be updated. If it's True or False the SimpleCheck will be "true". If left on indeterminate, it will be "False".

Comment: Right, no exception thrown. I'm sorry, you're right with this mistake, made it recently but it didn't work before  by setting it with check.simplecheck = box.IsChecked().Value
I mean it can be null but this method default value it's false. "true if the ToggleButton is checked; false if the ToggleButton is unchecked; otherwise null. The default is false."

Comment: So a breakpoint in there gets hit and SaveChanges is called? When investigating issues like this I'll commonly use breakpoints on the SaveChanges call, inspect the data before the SaveChanges executes (if an update) then inspect it immediately after the SaveChanges to verify the record change has persisted, before letting it continue. In some cases the culprit is further code down the stack executing and undoing the change, or a race condition. (Works when stepping through, fails when left to run unattended.)

Comment: Yes, it's called and data seemed ok all time. Caught what it was, will explain in answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Error source was in the model

```
public bool? SimpleCheck { get; set; }
```

As there are no booleans in sqlite it seems that the ef core converter fails somewhere if its nullable, it assigns null if false and 0 if true, while expected results are 0 and 1. Reproduced in a test solution. Just making it non-nullable and adjusting null-checks at code did the trick.